# how to change value of a variable in a Delphi executable? without sources

Tags: delphi

Sorry for my bad english.
I have an delphi application exe. 
it writes "log" files in the directory "c:\". this causes Windows security bugs.

how can I change the value of a variable (inside in exe)

ex:
drive := 'c:\';
 to 
drive := 'p:\';

or :

stringlist.savetofile('c:\log.txt');
 to 
stringlist.savetofile('p:\log.txt')

any way to do this without sources?

Comment: Have you tried any exe resource explorer tool? There are several out there capable of editing strings inside exe.

Comment: I use "Hex Workshop" for this kind of things. Note that this will break your app if it's digitally signed. and if the exe is packed for some reason, you will need to unpack  it first.

Answer (score 3):

If it is just about changing c:\ to p:\ then you can use a hex editor of your choice and search for the text you want to change in the executable file. Changing the length of the string (like changing c:\log.txt to c:\log\log.txt) is not usually possible.

If the log file is always c:\log.txt you can consider adding read/write permissions to this particular file only.

Comment: A good hex editor typically has a search function. Keep in mind that the strings might be stored as Unicode data. In that case you will have to tell the hex editor that it needs to search as Unicode. This assumes that the text is stored in the executable as plain text. If the .exe is compressed or otherwise protected, then you will have to remove the protection first, but that is probably not easy.

Comment: @Sergio Your question doesn't ask that.